# How to hide/show wxPanel at runtime?

Tags: wxwidgets

I want to make a panel on form visible/invisible at runtime like this:

```
wxPanel* wxp;
wxp->Hide();
...
wxp->Show();
```

Is it possible in some way?

Comment: This doesn't work?  What happens?

Comment: 2@ravenspoint: I wrote this code intuitively. I didn't even try to compile it, that was my fault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do it exactly like that as [wxPanel](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_panel.html) inherits from [wxWindow](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html) which provides methods called [Hide](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#7ed103df04014cb3c59c6a3fb4d95328) and [Show](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#7fbc92ce240a8d4f6956b6e0276ef07f).

So the following code should work:

```
wxPanel* wxp = new wxPanel(parent);
wxp->Hide();
...
wxp->Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using AUIManager I had to do the following:

```
void dlgFrame::OnShowToggleShowHideBtnVarClick(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    AuiManagerDxVar->GetPane(MyPanelVar).Show(event.IsChecked());
    AuiManagerDxVar->Update();
}
```

The button is basically a check/toggle button that has 2 status: checked or not checked (similarly to check-boxes).
the **event.IsChecked()** gets its checked status and returns it to the Show() method that shows the wxPanel **MyPanelVar** if it is true or hides it if it is false.

Also in my case the code doesn't work if I don't add the second row to update the AUIManager:

```
AuiManagerDxVar->Update();
```

Without that code basically I just see the frame flickering and nothing else happens.